# progress-bar changes color based on the value

Tags: bootstrap-4, field

I have a **progress_profile** field where I enter values from 1 to 100 in mysql,

```
$progress = $row['progress_profile'];
```

in the bootstrap-bar code I put this code

```
<p class="bioheading">Profile Completed Progess</p>
<div class="progress">

<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $progress; ?>%;"><?php echo $progress . '% Profile Completed'; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like based on the values entered in **progress_profile**,
change the color of the bar

example"

from 1 to 49 red color

from 50 to 90 blue color

from 91 to 100 green color

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$progress = $row['progress_profile'];
$color = '';
if ($progress > 90) {
    $color = 'green';
}else if($progress >= 50){
    $color = 'blue';
}else{
    $color = 'red';
}
?>
```

Add this snippet before the progress bar!.

In your code for progress bar set the style `background-color` of div with `$color` as shown..

Hence your code should be...

```
<p class="bioheading">Profile Completed Progess</p>
<div class="progress">

<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $progress; ?>%;background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $progress . '% Profile Completed'; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

### One Suggestion For You:

Instead of manually setting colors you should implement it this way,
by using bootstrap standard colors!

Changes:

Snippet:

```
<?php
$progress = $row['progress_profile'];
$color = 'bg-';
if ($progress > 90) {
    $color .= 'success';
}else if($progress >= 50){
    $color .= 'primary';
}else{
    $color .= 'danger';
}

?>
```

progress bar code:

```
<p class="bioheading">Profile Completed Progess</p>
    <div class="progress ">

    <div class="progress-bar <?php echo $color ?>" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $progress; ?>%;"><?php echo $progress . '% Profile Completed'; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

> Note: you can add the snippet inline, but add it after the `$progress['progress_profile']`.

Comment: does not work,
does not take data from the field $progress = $row['progress_profile'];

Comment: Alex add the snippet exactly after `$progress = $row['progress_profile']`

Comment: takes it from here  `$progress = 60.0;`

Comment: yes remove this line I have just added it for demo purpose!

Comment: could you share a picture, of what are your getting , browser screenshot?

Comment: One more question, is it setting the progress of the progress bar correcty, or just the color mechanism is wrong... also please share your bootstrap version, as progress bar colour in old version must be set as 'progress-bar-danger' etc.

Comment: the point is wrong, removed
look here
1% red (it works
51% blue (does not work)
100% blue (does not work)   https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Comment: Yes I am exactly asking that what is not working? could you share screenshots!

Comment: bootstrap 4 my version, screen https://yadi.sk/d/LxBa2_BFS2ksKQ

Comment: check this out it is working on mine https://imgur.com/a/XvagIfa

Comment: First please check by setting the class manually to progress bar and then add code!

Comment: solved, changed `$color .= 'success';` with `$color = 'progress-bar-success';` , `$color .= 'primary';` with `progress-bar-warning`,   `$color .= 'danger ';`  with  `'progress-bar-danger`, now work, Thank you Sankalp          `

Comment: No problem! Alex

Comment: yes accepted, you programmer? you have github o blog address?

Comment: Ha, I am just a junior college student I haven't made any blog o GitHub page...